# Test if a webpage was opened succesfully via intent using Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am having simple function as Below

```
fun openWebPage(url: String) {
    val openURL = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    openURL.data = Uri.parse(url)
    startActivity(openURL)
}
```

How to test and verify that webpage is opened successfully using Robolectric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet helped to capture that scenario

```
    val shadow = Shadows.shadowOf(activity)
    val exp_url = "www.google.com"
    val intent =  shadow.nextStartedActivity
    val url = intent.data.toString()
    assertEquals(exp_url,url)
```